# C# ASP.net MVC database questions

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, database, visual-studio

I am trying to develop a website with C# ASP.net MVC. It's my first time using Visual Studio, C# and ASP.net so I have lots to learn but so far so good.
So far... I started a C# ASP.net MVC project and added a database by going to the Database Explorer and clicking "add connection". I then did some standard CRUD controllers and views.

I am at the stage where I want to implement User authentication. I'm a bit confused here. I am trying to make a custom Membership Provider. So I added it to my web.config file with the correct connection string etc.
When I run the project and go to register I get an error. "Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'."

From searching, I see lots of people have this problem and they always reference their hosting. People say this (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/08/25/423703.aspx) is their solution but when I try pick a database I get an error. Not even sure of my server name.
So at this point I am wondering, did I set up the database right?

**EDIT**

Adding in a few pics to show exactly what I am doing. This is the aspnet_regsql.exe:
[image]
[image]

This is the provider with connection string, taken from an example on one of the links given.
[image]
This is my customized provider with connection string pointing to the last image.
[image]

This is a screen cap when I run the project and go to the default project Account register action:
[image]

and finally, this is the error screen when I submit
[image]

**EDIT**

Another update..

I sorted something out but I am not sure if it is correct. I am now getting an error when the page loads: "Invalid object name 'dbo.Tag'"

Comment: Have you run the aspnet_regsql program to create the tables and stored procedures in your database?

Comment: Not answering your question specifically here, because I do not know what it is that causes your error, but if you're new to C# Asp.net MVC, then I highly recommend building the Nerd Dinner example as your first ap. It makes for a really in depth example, and can be completed within a day. It's probably the best way to learn the basics. http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/ has a copy of the PDF tutorial.

Comment: @tvan I think he's trying to create a custom membership provider. Not sure if the default aspnet schema is required for that or not.

Comment: @tvan Running that program, the second screen asks for "Server" and "Database". Running with default settings and going to the next screen, my server name is my laptop's name and my database is "aspnetdb". The next button then tries to connect to it I think and I get an error saying: "System.Web.HttpException Unable to connect to SQL Server database --> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClient.SqlException"

Comment: Is aspnetdb located on your App_Data folder?

Comment: Try `aspnet_regsql.exe -E -S localhost -A m -d your-database-name-here`.  Use `-A mr` if you need both membership and roles.  This is assuming that you are using the default SQL membership provider or extending it.

Comment: @Roger, set the LocalSqlServer connection string to attach that db. Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

In order to solve this problem the only thing you need to do is create an [application services DB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74.aspx). You can achieve this by running the following command from your Visual Studio Command Prompt

```
aspnet_regsql
```

Anyways it seems that your "custom provider" isn't using a custom structure for your DB, which might be the reason why you weren't expecting this error.

If you are using the default implementation, you can access to the user administration using ASP .NET Configuration, located on your project menu in visual studio.

The default implementation uses the following conn string keyword

```
LocalSqlServer
```

The are many ways of implementing the membership provider. My guess is that probably this conn string is not pointing to your aspnet services db, you could do something like this to specify a custom location for this db

```
<remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
<add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I made a blog post regarding this topic: [How to use MembershipRole Provider and when to use custom implementations](http://mrroa.com/Blog/How-to-use-MembershipRole-Provider-and-when-to-use-custom-implementations)

Comment: My username and password are my Windows ones?

Comment: No, I updated the answer. Now the connstring attaches the mdf located on your App_Data using integrated auth.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to figure out anything from your post.

> but when I try pick a database I get
>   an error.

You can check your server name in Surface area configuration or Sql Server Configuration Manager. If you installed Visual Studio it's probably YOUR_MACHINE_NAME\SQLEXPRESS. You can connect to it using Windows Authentication. You could also write localhost,1433 instead, but that would require enabling TCP/IP first(it's disabled by default) and setting the port number first(which in most cases is already set).

Comment: Thanks, without the \SQLEXPRESS, I wasn't able to do anything with the aspnet_regsql.exe.